# Numpy: Comparing array elements within another array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
X = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [1,2], [5,6]]
```

I want a numpy array `Y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]`, where `[1,2]` is replaced by `1`, `[3,4]` replaced by `2` and so on. This is for a very large (think millions) X.

Intuition is `Y[X == [1,2]] = 1`. But this does't work.

Comment: How/where are those search patterns : `[1,2]`, `[3,4]`, etc. stored? Or do you have just two such patterns?

Comment: You have a 2D list and in python level it's simply possible but since you tagged the `numpy` as well, if you mean that `X` is supposed to be a numpy array, this is not possible. By that I mean you cannot convert a 2d array into a  undetermined shaped array.

Comment: Good point - I will change the question to indicate it is a numpy array. The search patterns can be stored in a separate array if need be - those are small in number (like 20)

Answer (score 0):

> *Intuition is `Y[X == [1,2]] = 1`. But this does't work.*

Here is how to make it work:

```
Y = np.empty(len(X), dtype=np.int)
Y[np.all(X == [1, 2], 1)] = 1
```

To process all the possible values:

```
s = set(map(tuple, X))
r = np.arange(1, len(s) + 1) # or assign whatever values you want
cond = [np.all(X == v, 1) for v in s]
Y = np.dot(r, cond)
```